# Please Help!! How to Use GET for Nuxt Apollo?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

The queries are working with POST by default.
But I need to change it into GET . And I couldn't figure out

```
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
        default: {
            httpEndpoint: process.env.apolloServer,
            persisting: true,
            useGETForHashedQueries: true,
            useGETForQueries: true,
            fetchOptions: {
                useGETForQueries: true
            }
        },
```

Comment: Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: I found this tip helpful https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/365#issuecomment-733029476